# How do render the DatePickerAndroid component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, android-datepicker

The docs provide an example:

```
try {
  const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
    // Use `new Date()` for current date.
    // May 25 2020. Month 0 is January.
    date: new Date(2020, 4, 25)
  });
  if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
    // Selected year, month (0-11), day
  }
} catch ({code, message}) {
  console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
}
```

but it's unclear to me how exactly I'm supposed to where/how to render . I put the try block inside ComponentDidMount lifecycle method, but I got an error "await is a reserved word".  When I removed the word 'await' I got a new error:  'Cannot call a class a function'.

For the time being, I'm simply returning a View with a DatePickerAndroid inside.

Answer (score 2):

My brain apparently isn't working today.  To use it, I just created a TouchableOpacity component which fired a custom method "openUpPicker" which contained the example try block from the docs.

```
openUpPicker() {
        try {
            const {action, year, month, day} = DatePickerAndroid.open({
              // Use `new Date()` for current date.
              // May 25 2020. Month 0 is January.
              date: new Date(2020, 4, 25)
            });
            if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
              // Selected year, month (0-11), day
            }
          } catch ({code, message}) {
            console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
          }
    }
```

The touchableopacity component was simple:

```
                   <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={()=>this.openUpPicker()}
                    >
                    <Text>hello</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Finally someone who does not think the rendering is so obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out this datepicker component  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-datepicker

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

VK1's example worked for me (10x again!) it's just that I had to use async/await in order to get the selected date, otherwise year, month etc. are all undefined:

**async** openUpPicker(type)...

and then

const {action, year, month, day} = **await** DatePickerAndroid.open({....